# MySQL: Automatic data-operations

Tags: php, mysql

I've a MySQL Database with a table "products" and a lot of columns.

I've a column called `name` that have always a name-structure like this:
example

```
GD 0001 / PL40 
GD 0034 / PL60
GD 0106 / PL30
GD 0122 / 2S
```

etc

In the same table `products` I have another column, `image`.
It's possible to fill this field automatically relying on field `products`?

I'm trying to obtain this result:

```
gd0001_pl40.jpg
gd0034_pl40.jpg
gd0106_pl30.jpg
gd0122_2s.jpg
```

If necessary I can use PHP or SQL

Thank you, hope my question is understandable

Comment: Check my solution, I tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the actual values converted, first run this SQL:

```
UPDATE products SET 
image=LOWER(CONCAT(REPLACE((REPLACE(name," ","")),'/','_'),'','.jpg'));
```

After if you want total automatic conversion, you can crete two triggers, which will do it for you on INSERT and UPDATE:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER products_ins BEFORE INSERT ON products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  NEW.image = LOWER(CONCAT(REPLACE((REPLACE(NEW.name," ","")),'/','_'),'','.jpg'));
END;

CREATE TRIGGER products_ins BEFORE UPDATE ON products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  NEW.image = LOWER(CONCAT(REPLACE((REPLACE(NEW.name," ","")),'/','_'),'','.jpg'));
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

This way if you update your `name` field your `image` field will be auto-updated.

Answer (score 3):

1. Replace space with empty space
2. Replace / with _
3. concat .jpg at the end

Use `select  concat(REPLACE((REPLACE(column_name," ","")),'/','_'),'','.jpg') from table_name`

> You can add a function to convert this whole string to small case, you
>   can do that in mysql as well as in php on application layer

Comment: Might as well use the [`LCASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lcase) function.

Comment: You could put this into a view, if you don't want to explicit write it again and again.

Comment: @frlan this isn't something really huge to calculate again and again :) I guess it is better to call it as it is to avoid the over head..probably he will be calling it just once to view any report..

Comment: Hmmm... Was thinking of using it in different places. But sure, it's not a 100line script ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to write your own logic to get this. you may use javascript or java(String replace(),split()) methods.